# in pandoc how can I use per-section reference list for url link?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I have following code

```
# Section 1

[Link to Example 1][1]

[1]: https://example1

# Section 2

[Link to Example 2][1]

[1]: https://example2
```

however, it is always link to last [1] which is example2 at here.

Is there a way to make the [n]: list per section?